# Redefinition member of the namespace into the nested inline namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, inline, language-lawyer

There is a quote from 7.3.1/8 of N3797:

> Members of an inline namespace can be used in most respects as though
>   they were members of the enclosing namespace.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
namespace M
{
    int j = 7;
    inline namespace MM
    {
        int j = 8;
    }
}
```

I think that the example violates the `ODR`. But it is not true and it is compiling successful. Can you explain that behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Introduction

> `7.3p1` **Namespaces** `[basic.namespace]`
>
> > A namespace is an optionally-named declarative region. The name of a namespace can be used to access entities declared in that namespace; that is, the members of the namespace. Unlike other declarative regions, the definition of a namespace can be split over several parts of one or more translation units.

A declared entity inside a namespace belongs to that namespace, ie. it's a member of that specific namespace, no matter if the namespace is *inline* or not.

---

#### ODR VIOLATION = *N0NE*

Your example snippet does **not** violate the *ODR*, mainly because you have 2 **different** entities named `j`;

```
namespace N {
  int j = 0;            // 1st

  inline namespace M {
    int j = 1;          // 2nd
  }
}
```

As pointed out further down in `[namespace.def]p8`, name lookup in the enclosing namespace will include those found in any `inline` namespace, but the members of the nested inline namespace are still entities of their own.

> `7.3.1p8` **Namespace definition** `[namespace.def]`
>
> > Specifically, the inline namespace and its enclosing namespace are both added to the set of associated namespaces used in argument-dependent lokoup (3.4.2) whenever one of them is, and a using-direction (7.3.4) that names the inline namespace is implicitly inserted into the enclosing namespace as for an unnamed namespace (7.3.1.1).
> >
> > Furthermore, each member of the inline namespace can subsequently be explicitly instantiated (14.7.2) or explicitly specialized (14.7.3) as though it were a member of the enclosing namespace. Finally, lookup up a name in the enclosing namespace via explicit qualification (3.4.3.2) will include members of the inline namespace brought in by the using-directive even if there are declarations of the name in the enclosing namespace.

The added names are not treated as redeclarations of previously declared entities, they are additional names, in a nested declarative region, that are brought into the enclosing namespace during name-lookup.

---

> <sup>**Note**: Relying on the compiler to issue a diagnostic in terms of ODR-violations is not safe, mainly because the Standard explicitly states that *"no diagnostic [is] required"* if an application violates the rules set up by `[basic.def.odr].`
>
> Further details are avaiable in a comment by [Matthieu M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147192/matthieu-m) on this post.</sup>

Comment: Specifically (for the note): detecting multiple entities with the same name but different definitions *across translation units* is hard. The compiler itself only often sees one translation unit at once, so the diagnostic falls onto the linker. The linker will diagnose a duplicate symbol for regular symbols, however `inline` functions (and thus `template` functions) are weak-symbols and linkers generally just pick one and ignore the others... This may change with modules.